# How can I translate my website with Translate?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, translate

I developed a project with Nuxt JS. There are texts from the service that are static inside. I want to automatically translate all of these texts like Google Translate. How can I do this for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For free, you will probably have only one solution: do it by hand thanks to [i18n](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/).

Otherwise, you could probably programmatically generate your pages with a paid API like Deepl or alike. A google search may help you here.

PS: SO is not a how-to website, but rather a "here is how to solve your issue given the code details you provided to us".